# Reinstall Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I hade a problem with scaffolding in Asp.Net MVC 5 and Visual studio 2013
I tried to reinstall the extension "Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding" by first uninstalled it. But I cant find any way to install it again.

I tried to repair visual studio. - no luck
I tried to uninstall visual studio and install visual studio, but the extension is still missing

Do I have to reinstall the PC or is there a quick fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by deleting pendling delete in the registy + deleted AppData for Visual studio

AppData will be recreated at startup of vs

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add to Chrille's answer.

The PendingDeletes can be found in

```
HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Exp\ExtensionManager
```

And

```
 HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ExtensionManager
```

And I found the AppData in my local and Roaming app data.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did.  It was a bit more involved than what everyone else was reporting.  I tried doing a repair in the Control Panel, it ran for several hours and then failed.  Perhaps my problems were that I installed VS2013 sp1 and then upgraded it to SP4 before I removed "Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding."

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Premium with Update 4 and then did a repair using that file, but the extension was still missing.  I then found the AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi in the en_visual_studio_premium_2013_with_update_4_x86_dvd_5935086.iso and did an uninstall and a reinstall, but the extension was still missing.

I extracted the packages\WPT\AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi file from my .iso file using msiexec.  In order to get the .msi file to extract successfully, I also had to place the *.cab files from \packages\WPT into the same folder I was extracting the .msi from.  Once I'd extracted my msi file, I went into it's folder structure and found the Scaffolding stuff.  It was in Dest\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Stack 5\VS_12_COMMON7_IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding folder.

Once I had that, I still didn't have a .vsix file that I could install into Visual Studio.  So what I did was create my own .vsix file.  I did a little research on the web and created a file called [Content_Types].xml, it's literally called that.  I renamed the file extension on several .vsix files that I had downloaded on my system to .zip and looked inside them to see what the contents of my [Content_Types].xml should look like, here's what I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="dll" ContentType="application/octet-stream" />
  <Default Extension="pkgdef" ContentType="text/plain" />
  <Default Extension="vsixmanifest" ContentType="text/xml" />
  <Default Extension="txt" ContentType="text/plain" />
</Types>
```

I then zipped up [Content_Types].xml, extension.vsixmanifest, and Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Mvc.5.0.dll to a zip file called Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Mvc.5.0.zip.  I then renamed that .zip file to Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Mvc.5.0.vsix.  I then was able to install the extension using this .vsix file that I created.

Answer (score 1):

I found that uninstall the AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi in the vs2013 ISO. And install it.

Comment: I did this, but the "Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding" is still missing for me.

Comment: To clarify a bit, if I'm reading your answer correctly, I believe that you uninstalled AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi in the vs2013 iso and then reinstalled it and the "Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding" appeared in your extensions list again?  I did this, but the "Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding" is still missing for me.

Comment: I did poke around in AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi with Super Orca and found C_VISUALSTUDIO_Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Mvc.5.0.dll inside it.  I tried doing a repair on it as well, but "Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding" is still missing from Visual Studio.

Comment: I've used msiexec in my command line to extract the contents of AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi to a directory.  I've found the folder that seems to contain the scaffolding (VS_12_COMMON7_IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding), but I can't figure out a way to install it.  Inside that folder I see extension.vsixmanifest and Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Mvc.5.0.dll plus a templates folder.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I did...

1) I uninstalled the scaffolding through Visual Studio.

2) Deleted the registry from:

`HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ExtensionManager\PendingDeletes`

3) Went to Control Panel > Programs

4) Select Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 > Hit Change

5) Choose Repair.

Pretty simple, but a little time consuming

Comment: I did this, still the ""Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have 7zip installed.
2. Download the full iso of [visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx).
3. extract the iso to a folder.
4. Go to \packages\WPT within that folder.
5. Run AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi
6. Uninstall.
7. Run AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi
8. Install.

That should do it.

To verify, create a new MVC project, and try to add a scaffold item. Don't verify with an existing project, because that may be a whole different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the MVC controllers in scaffolding (only able to select Web API 2), then after removing MVC 5 scaffolding to reinstall I could not get it installed again.

I found downloading the .iso for VS 2013 update 4, extracting to a folder, then running AspNetWebFrameworksTools_VS12_ENU.msi to uninstall, then again to reinstall, then rebooting resolved both issues.  I am now able to add controller, and I have MVC 5 controllers to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove the Registry keys, the AppData and the folder in this location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions`. After this, I repaired the VisualStudio from Programs and Features in control panel. I was desperate because even I uninstalled and re-installed again and the extension was not visible.