# project on visual studio 2012 be open on visual studio 2013 cannot add view or controller

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a project web mvc3 be created on Visual Studio 2012, now i open this project on Visual Studio 2013 IDE, build is ok but I cannot quick add new controller!

this is my screen!
http://s07.img-up.net/check6d26.png

helps me,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this error:

We need Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317645

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the project is not currently running in debug mode. If it is, press the red button and stop it. Now you can add, just right click on the Controller folder and select Add - Controller.

Comment: I don't running debug mode! when I create new project in current solution, I can add new controller in this new project just create, but old project still cannot add!

Comment: It seems like the MVC3 project does not know where to find the Templates for adding a new controller. Go to Tools | Options and click on "Projects and Solutions" You want to make sure that they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**!!! READ THIS IF YOU HAVE VISUAL STUDIO 2010 & 2013 VERSIONS INSTALLED !!!!**

I ran in to this issue when I opened the project with Visual Studio 2013, I tried going the "Update to MVC4 route" mentioned above, that did not work out as expected. Right there it hit me! "why not open the project with VS 2010, add the controller, then save and resume using 2013?" - I did just that and it worked!. simple right?