# No Add Controller option on menu in MVC 3.0 VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

Not geting the `Add-> Controller` In my MVC 3.0 Project.

**Try**:- Changing the `<ProjectGuid>` and `<ProjectTypeGuids>` in csproj as suggested by  lot of similar questions but noon paid off

```
<ProjectGuid>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}</ProjectGuid>
<!--<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>-->
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

tried a lot of GUID nothing Working..

I am using `Visual Studio professional 2013 V12.0.31101.00 Update4`

[Already tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849812/visual-studio-2013-add-controller-missing) this accepted answer and others too it doesn't work in my case 
[image]

Comment: Hi, the controller is only a class that must inherit from Controller, so go ahead and create a new class and put this class to inherit from Controller.

Comment: @VishalSuthar  U can see i already tried that answer

Comment: @JulitoAvellaneda  i know that i can do so but is there any specific reason why it is not there..

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this before editing project:

Open VS2013=>TOOLS=>Customize. 
Select Commands. 
Select Context menu. 
Select Project and Solution Context Menus|Folder|Add. 
Check whether there is Controller in it. 
Please move up Controller item to the top.