# No templates when starting a new ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have created many web application, but today when I tried the create one I was greeted with the following dialog box.

[image]

Has anyone run into this or have any ideas on how to fix?  I have tried repairing Visual Studio. I have tried uninstalling "Microsoft Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC 5 Scaffolding" and then repairing Visual studio. I have tried a command line switch /InstallVSTemplates at the visual studio command line. I have tried the items here [Reinstall Microsoft Visual Studio Asp.net MVC 5 Scaffolding extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835385/reinstall-microsoft-visual-studio-asp-net-mvc-5-scaffolding-extension).  Nothing is working. I still have an empty dialog box shown above.

Anyone have any ideas before I completely uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: Running into the same problem.  Not sure if it happened during the last update of Web Essentials?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270008/cant-create-new-mvc5-project-or-any-other-asp-net-projects-in-visual-studio-20

Answer (score 2):

The link MikeJansen posted in the comments above fixed it. Thanks Mike!

[Can't create new MVC5 project or any other ASP .NET projects in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270008/cant-create-new-mvc5-project-or-any-other-asp-net-projects-in-visual-studio-20)

I followed the solution provided by xinqiu

1. Close VS.
2. Goto C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
3. Delete the following assemblies if they exist:

   1. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll
   2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll
   3. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll